# Only load html parts when the user has a specific role in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Currently all my users are built in my app something like this:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: 'John Doe',
 roles: [{name: 'owner'}, {name: 'admin'}, {name: 'client'}]
}
```

I have a Dashboard in my application that should only show parts of the application to users who have a specific role. Lets say only a owner should be able to create or delete something. Can I do something like this in the html to let only admin and owner be able to see that piece of html? so I give the current users roles and tell what roles he should have for the button.

```
<button
   class="btn btn-danger"
   permission="vm.user.roles | {'admin', 'owner'}"
   Delete
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` will remove the element from DOM if the condition is false.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="vm.hasRole('admin') || vm.hasRole('owner')">
   Delete
</button>
```

If you want to just hide the element rather than remove it, you can use `ng-show` instead.

In your controller:

```
$scope.hasRole = function(roleName) {
    return user.roles.filter(function(role) {
        return role.name === roleName;
    }).length > 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will work since the roles are objects in a array.

Comment: Try it. `user.roles` is an array so you can use `filter` function. `role` is the actual object inside the array, so `role.name` should give you the role name.

Comment: It says `Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'vm.user.roles.filter')` ( vm.user.roles is the array ) Is it because the vm.user object might not be retrieved before hasRole is fired in the html?

Comment: you can show code where your `user` object is defined?

Comment: nvm it works now I just do a if vm.user === undefined a single return; and it solved the problem

Comment: you should do a `ng-if="vm.user"` in your html template before you access the `vm.user` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function indexOf in array to find whether a element is part of the array. It will return the position of the element if found or will return -1.

So you can use an expression like below

```
<button
   class="btn btn-danger"
   ng-show = "['admin', 'owner'].indexOf(roles)!=-1">
   Delete
</button>
```

Comment: ah sorry my roles looks a little bit different I have changed my post. Its an array of objects and not an array of values/strings.